# How to prevent user from redirecting to restricted page in django

Tags: python, django

I have created a login page for my website, but when I manually type in the URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/, it will redirect them to the home page even when they have not login yet, how do I prevent this from happening?

Views.py

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_admin:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You have login to admin page")
            return redirect('home')
        elif user is not None and user.is_customer:  # authenticated if user is a customer service
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('customer')  # redirect the user to the customer service page

        elif user is not None and user.is_logistic:  # # authenticated if user is a logistic
            messages.success(request, "You have login to logistic page")
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('logistic')  # redirect the user to the logistic page

        else:
            messages.success(request, "try Again")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
     urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
        path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
        path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
        path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
        path('edit-register/', views.edit_register_view, name='edit_register'),
        path('change-password/', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
        path('reset-password/', views.PasswordReset.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
        path('reset-password-done/', views.PasswordResetDone.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
        path('reset-password/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirm.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
        path('reset-password-complete/', views.PasswordResetComplete.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Login required decorator - > [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Add like this in your view

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def your_view(request):
    ...
```

To redirect unauthenticated users to login page update your view page like so

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def your_view(request):
    ...
```

---

Tip - Try to use Class Based Views, handling the functionality will be easier. If you decide to use class based views you will be using LoginRequiredMixin -> [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)

Comment: Hi, I add a @login_required, but when I type the Url manually, it gives me an error saying that the page is not found and the url it appear is not the url i wanted

Comment: So, you are getting a 404, Page not found error. That is good. That is exactly what you should expect when you restrict someone. If you want to redirect the user to 404 Page not found you can implement this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view.
If you want to re-direct to some other page or functionality you have to implement middleware.

Comment: I want to redirect the users back to the login page no matter how many times they try to access the home page, is there any example on how to use the middleware?

Comment: i have another questions, can I implement the @login_required as many times as I want, like I have a register page but is only admin able to access it and I want both the home page and register page restrict the user from accessing it unless they login

Comment: Updated answer - Redirect users back to login page.

Yes you can use it as many times as you want. My suggestion is to move to Class Based Views. It is easier.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help, will try out the class based views and see if it works

Comment: can I get an upvote too, so that other people who need help can also find this post useful?

Comment: @Shadowwalker Sure.